# Can you return to Skyhold during DA:I The Descent

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Once you start The Descent DLC, are you able to go back to Skyhold, or is it like The Trespasser in that it locks you in to the new campaign until you've completed it? I heard that there's a new variant of the war table inside the Deep Roads, so I'm a little bit concerned about starting it and getting locked in by accident.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Descent DLC is like the Jaws of Hakkon.  After the intro, you can exit back to the main map and enter other areas like Skyhold at your will.  You're not trapped there, unlike with Trespasser.